# How to add custom properties to custom constructors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I want to make a custom javascript **constructor** with custom **properties**. Lets imagine of how it may look like :

```
 var a = new MyCustomConstructor({
  selector: ".demo",
  html: "Hello World !",
  style: {
     color : "white",
     background : "blue"
  }
 });
```

The above example adds the text **Hello World !** to all the elements with class **demo** with given styles. How can I make this happen actually ? I will like to achieve it with **ES5** but also **ES6** where necessary but no library. Can I do it ? If yes then how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a quite good solution to that. So, here is a piece of code :

```
 function MyCustomConstructor(stock) {
   var sel = document.querySelectorAll(stock.selector); // Selecting all matching elements in your selector method
   for( var i = 0; i < sel.length; ++i ) {
     sel[i].innerHTML += stock.html; // Setting the text 
     sel[i].style.cssText = stock.style; // Setting css properties with values
     sel[i].style[stock.css.prop] = stock.css.val; // You can also nest them
   };
 };
```

You can use it as :

```
 var a = new MyCustomConstructor({
   selector: ".demo",
   html: "Hello World !",
   style: "background : blue",
   css: {
      prop: "color",
      val: "white",
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> The above example adds the text Hello World ! to all the elements with class demo. 
>   How can I make this happen actually

Answering your question you can simply find all elements with `class=demo` and set their text:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (let el of elements) {
  el.innerText = 'Hello World!'
}
```

```html
<span class='demo'>

</span>

<span class='demo'>

</span>

<span class='demo'>

</span>
```

Also I'd advise you to read about js constructors [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp) good article.